# NSButton binding to NSCollectionViewItem: representedObject?

Tags: objective-c, swift, binding, nsbutton, nscollectionviewitem

When I pre-added a button to the NSCollectionViewItem's view, I can bind its action in the inspector:

[image]

Which works without problem.

Now I'd like to create that button programmatically within the view's `mouseDown:`, what should I assign to the `bind:` option for the same result as the  "Bind to: Collection View Item" in inspector?

Here's the code: (Swift)

```
aButton!.bind(
    "argument",
    toObject: ???, // <- what should I set here?
    withKeyPath: "representedObject",
    options: options
)
```

**EDIT:** I was able to do it by subclassing **NSCollectionView** then override `newItemForRepresentedObject:` to assign the *representedObject* to the subclass view.

Still like to know if there are ways without subclassing **NSCollectionView**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should bind to the `NSCollectionViewItem` instance which owns the view of which the button is a descendant.

From what context are you creating the button and trying to bind it? Is this in a controller of the collection view? Or is it in the collection view item itself (which is a controller of the collection view item view)? Or perhaps it's in custom view class, although that would be a bit strange.

From the controller of the collection view, you can use `-itemAtIndex:` to get the relevant collection view item.

From the collection view item, you would just use `self`. However, in this case bindings don't really get you much. You might as well just set the button's `target` and `action` and do something with the `representedObject` in the action method.

If you're doing this from a view, then you need a way to obtain a reference to the collection view item. You should add a weak outlet on the view that you connect to the collection view item in the NIB. Then, you would use that outlet to get the collection view item for that `bind()` call.

Comment: It's a custom view class, which used as prototype of the `NSCollectionViewItem`. I meant to create buttons only when mouse is at certain positions. so `itemAtIndex:` will not do. As from what I've read, a pre-linked IBOutlet to the prototype will not be copied when a new `NSCollectionViewItem` is being created. That's why I end up subclassing the `NSCollectionView`.

Comment: Since `NSCollectionViewItem` inherits from `NSViewController`, it can load its view from a NIB. So, you can create the prototype *item* (not view) in the NIB that has the collection view and just assign a NIB name to it on the attributes inspector. Then, you can define the item view in a separate view NIB. Set the class of that NIB's File's Owner to `NSCollectionViewItem` (or your custom subclass if you're using one). You can then set up an outlet and any other types of connections and they will be faithfully recreated when each actual item and item view is instantiated.

Comment: I'll accept this as answer for all the effort you put into this matter. Thanks.